# Complete the (alpha) sequence riddle

Tags: riddle, pattern, lateral-thinking, letter-sequence, connections-puzzle

> Fill in the blank below (as indicated by the underscore: "_") to complete the unique sequence:
>
> **T _ M R P**

**Rules/hints/clarifications:**

- The answer is to be in the form of an American-English alphabetical character, that is A through Z, for a total of 26 possible answer candidates values.
- The poster should be able to explain WHY supplied answer is the answer (so someone cant win with a lucky guess).
- Ignore white-space, ignore case; the spaces are not a part of the riddle, I just put them there for formatting. Similarly, the case of the character is irrelevant; I'm looking for one of the 26 American-English alphabetical characters.
- The presence of a hint character (T, M, R, or P) does not preclude it from being in the answer. In other words, just because the characters T, M, R, and P are already in the sequence does not mean that it eliminates them as a possibility for being the answer.
- There is a discrete answer, this is not a 'trick question'. The sequence is not arbitrary, and represents a real sequence that exists in the real world, and can be observed *IN NATURE*.
- In fact, I am almost certain that everyone who reads this has observed this sequence before.
- *In fact, I am almost certain that you can observe this pattern right now, from where you sit.*
- *There is actually 2 acceptable answers, that is, there are actually 2 different characters that you can put in blank and make a valid sequence, and thus, is acceptable as a correct answer.*
- *I will answer any questions about the puzzle, as long as they are phrased as a YES/NO question.*

Good luck!

Comment: Posting the answer but not the explanation wouldn't be that great in a puzzle where the possible answers are only 26. If you confirm that it is (or not) the correct solution, the puzzle is half-ruined, instead if you don't comment the post, it's just a low-quality answer. So, I would discourage unexplained answers; on the contrary, if you want to post a partial answer (aka a hint), it would be good.

Comment: I agree with your points. I have edited my question to not contain ambiguity about posting the reason WHY the supplied answer belongs there. I also have 'revealed' the 'hidden' clues.

Comment: Question: does the sequence contain only 5 elements? Is it possible to add a sixth element to it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer is **P** (or I).

Because the full list is actually:

> **T**humb
>  **P**ointer (or Index) finger
>  **M**iddle finger
>  **R**ing finger
>  **P**inky